ttyACM Increasing maximum USB packet size
I am working with a virtual serial port over USB (using the ACM driver). I have noticed that, when parsing some packets, I am missing data.  After putting a bunch of log statements in, I noticed that I am not even receiving the data in my code. So, I loaded tshark on my Linux box and saw that the packets over a certain size from the USB device are being split into two separate packets. Is there a way to increase the "buffer" size in the driver or kernel so the data is not split between two packets (and therefore two epoll events)? Please note, that these sizes are not necessarily "big" (less than 1kb).

The USB packet size on the wire is entirely determined by the device itself.  That's just a fact of life.  It is your responsibility to combine the packets into a  buffer.

I get the full size over Windows, so I am not sure it is the device.

Then it might be the generic USB Serial driver; that's the code that decides how large of a request to submit to the lower levels.  In any case, there is no entity in the world -- other than your application -- that knows how large your transfers might be.  Serial ports are streams, not packets.  It is entirely your responsibility to put things back together.

"I am working ... using the ACM driver ... I am missing data." - Then instead of trying to find a workaround just for your project, you need to document and report this alleged bug so that it can be fixed in the kernel for all users. However, the last time I read of such a problem, it was due to an improper termios configuration. Otherwise this is an XY question.

The high-level model for data received from a serial port is that it's a stream of bytes, with no particular demarcation of packets.  The fact that there are system calls that let you read more than one byte at a time is just something that is done for efficiency, and you should not rely on any of the details of that: you have seen that they are just implementation details which depend on your computer.  You need to be able to process the incoming stream of bytes and find the message boundaries in your own code.  Consider making a processReceivedByte function that takes one byte.

The Linux cdc-acm driver uses a maximum read transfer length that is twice the maximum packet size of the receive endpoint. The maximum packet size will probably be 64 bytes, resulting in a maximum transfer size of 128 bytes. So up to 128 bytes of received data could be passed up to the TTY receive buffer in one go. It also has up to 16 of these read transfers queued up waiting for data from the USB device.
